# titanium ti.paint toimage() is returning {} after drawing on ios

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

the following code is resulting in to different outputs different android and ios.  myBlob below is {} on ios - the image is empty even after drawing on the screen.  in Android it an object with properties and is working fine, but iOS the image is always blank.

This was working before in past ios versions and builds so am I not building it right? We are using 5.3.0 GA for titanium SDK. I have the module checked for iOS in the TiApp Editor.

```
function uploadImage(signed) {
    if (signed) {
        var myBlob;
        try {  
            myBlob = $.viewPaint.toImage();
            var myImage = Titanium.Utils.base64encode(myBlob).toString(); 
            $.nextAction.image = myImage;
        } catch (ex) {
           Titanium.API.error('FAILURE HANDLING SIGNATURE DOCUMENT: ' + ex);
           return;
        }
    }

    $.nextAction.perform(Alloy.Globals.requests);
}
```

Ti Paint Module for iPhone

```
#
# this is your module manifest and used by Titanium
# during compilation, packaging, distribution, etc.
#
version: 1.4.0
apiversion: 2
architectures: armv7 i386 x86_64 arm64
description: Provides a paint surface user interface view.
author: Jeff Haynie 
license: Appcelerator Commercial License 
copyright: Copyright (c) 2010-2014 by Appcelerator, Inc. 


# these should not be edited
name: paint
moduleid: ti.paint
guid: 43f13063-d426-4e9c-8a7a-72dc5e4aec57
platform: iphone
minsdk: 3.4.1.GA
```

prior code that adds execute to action object

```
                var route = action.action.uri;
                Ti.API.info('route = ' + route);
                newAction.execute = function(requestManager) {
                    Titanium.App.fireEvent('app:index:view:requested', 
                        controller : 'signscreen',
                        uri : route
                    });
                };
```

code that fires the event to open:

```
            Titanium.App.fireEvent('app:index:view:requested', {
                controller : 'signature'
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have anything in your view hierarchy that overlays your paintview such as a confirmation dialog or closing the view in a navigation controller and not grabbing your paintview prior to the window closing the paintview will always return empty. android will continue to work fine but ios will not as the view is not present in the view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Your console log value of `{}` is a red herring.

Tested on:

- TiSDK 5.2.2.GA, 5.3.0.GA
- ti.paint: 1.4.0, 1.4.1 (our version with fixes that have been ignored by appc)
- With `<run-on-main-thread>false</run-on-main-thread>` in tiapp.xml

Using the example app.js from the module and adding the following:

```
var buttonSave = Ti.UI.createButton({ bottom:100, right:10, width:75, height:30,   title:'Save' });
buttonSave.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  var test = paintView.toImage();
  console.log(test.length); 
  console.log(paintView.toImage()); 
  var imageFile = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory,"testing.png");
  imageFile.write(paintView.toImage());
});
win.add(buttonSave)
```

You will find that

1. The logged value always will be `{}`
2. The length of the object you assigned toImage() to increases as you add pixels to your paintView
3. The image DOES get written to a file.

Comment: You will also find that `test` has width (`test.width`) and height (`test.height`)

Comment: Okay. So i must be doing something wrong because the length is always the same and the base 64 is always blank?

Comment: [INFO]  14162 for test.length always even when drawing on the screen.  the image is always blank.

Comment: See above - the image is blank always and has the same output for test.length.  Am i building the application wrong?